# How to autoupdate combobox with values from SQLite in JavaFX?

Tags: java, sqlite, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm writing an application with JavaFX, Scene Builder and SQlite

I have combobox with values(id) that goes from SQLite database.I have 2 textArias. I have a button "Add" that has a method `void addCard(ActionEvent event)`. The method add text from textArias and apply it to particular columns in SQLite.

The problem is: when I try to add values to SQLite and click a button and then I open combobox, I don't see added ID, but when I close the window and open it again combobox display my added id.

It is very annoying to close and open  window every time when I want to see the added result in combobox

- Model class holds all logic
- Controller Class operate between Model and view
- Persistent Queries class holds all queries to/from SQLite

How to display new added ID after clicking on the button "Add"?

This video shows how my application work:

[Video](https://mega.nz/#!jNd23SgD!-pygjAlyQvFM6XbXB9mKuJfbFpjJHJxKPw_oJoxuFQQ)

Model class:

```
package src.card;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Cards {

  PersistentQueries pq = new PersistentQueries();

  final ObservableList OPTIONS = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

  Connection connection;
  PreparedStatement pst = null;
  ResultSet rs = null;




  public Cards() {
try {
  this.connection = DbConnection.getConnection();
} catch (SQLException ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
}

if (this.connection == null) {
  System.out.println("connection is not successful!");
  System.exit(1);
}

  }


   public ObservableList getOPTIONS() {return OPTIONS;}



   //add ID of cards to combobox
  void fillCombobox() {
   try {
  pst = connection.prepareStatement(pq.getSqlSelectID());
  rs = pst.executeQuery();

  while (rs.next()) {
    OPTIONS.add(rs.getString("ID"));
  }

  pst.close();
  rs.close();

} catch (SQLException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }

  //check if database is connected
  public boolean isDbConnected() {
    return this.connection != null;
  }
}
```

**Controller Class:**

```
 package src.card;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import src.card.Cards;
import src.card.Context;
import src.card.DbConnection;
import src.card.PersistentQueries;

import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;




public class QuestController implements Initializable {

  @FXML  private TextArea ta_questText, ta_answerText;
  @FXML  private Label questId, error;
  @FXML  private ComboBox<String> combobox_question;

  Cards cards = new Cards();
  PersistentQueries pq = new PersistentQueries();

  @Override
  public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

//register QuestController in  Context Class
Context.getInstance().setQuestController(this);

cards.fillCombobox();
combobox_question.setItems(cards.getOPTIONS());

  }

//adding cards to database
 @FXML
  void addCard(ActionEvent event) {

    if (ta_questText.getText().equals("") || 
   ta_answerText.getText().equals("")) {
  error.setText("All fields are required!");
} else {
  try {
    error.setText("");
    Connection conn = DbConnection.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(pq.getSqlInsert());
    stmt.setString(1, this.ta_questText.getText());
    stmt.setString(2, this.ta_answerText.getText());
    ta_questText.setText("");
    ta_answerText.setText("");
    stmt.execute();
    conn.close();


  } catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }

  }

  @FXML
  void idList(ActionEvent event) {

  questId.setText(combobox_question.getValue() + ".");

   }
}
```

**PersistentQueries Class**

```
package src.card;

public class PersistentQueries {

  private String sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO Cards(question, answer) VALUES 
 (?,?)";
  private String sqlSelectID = "SELECT ID FROM Cards";
  private String sqlSelect = "SELECT question and answer FROM Cards";


  public String getSqlInsert() {
   return sqlInsert;
  }

  public void setSqlInsert(String sqlInsert) {
    this.sqlInsert = sqlInsert;
  }


  public String getSqlSelectID() {
   return sqlSelectID;
   }

  public void setSqlSelectID(String sqlSelectID) {
   this.sqlSelectID = sqlSelectID;
  }

   public String getSqlSelect() {
   return sqlSelect;
  }

  public void setSqlSelect(String sqlSelect) {
   this.sqlSelect = sqlSelect;
  }
}
```

Comment: You can either add the item to the combobox at the same time as adding it to the database, or reload the data from the database after adding it.

Comment: @Zephyr  how to reload data in combobox? can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM SOLVED!**

in QuestController in the method `@FXML  void addCard(ActionEvent event)` I added

```
cards.getOBS().clear();
```

It removes all objects from Observable list

then, I called method from Cards Class that reads all new data from SQLite and add it to Observable list

```
cards.fillCombobox();
```

and then I just close all connections:

```
    pst.close();
    rs.close();
    conn.close();
```

My rewritten method looks like this:

```
 /adding cards to database, update combobox and clear label text
  @FXML  void addCard(ActionEvent event) {

if (ta_questText.getText().equals("") || ta_answerText.getText().equals("")) {
  error.setText("All fields are required!");
} else {
  try {

    error.setText("");
    Connection conn = DbConnection.getConnection();
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(pq.getSqlInsert());
    pst.setString(1, this.ta_questText.getText());
    pst.setString(2, this.ta_answerText.getText());
    pst.execute();

    pst = conn.prepareStatement(pq.getSqlSelectID());
    rs = pst.executeQuery();

    ta_questText.clear();
    ta_answerText.clear();
    cards.getOBS().clear();
    questId.setText("");

   cards.fillCombobox();

    pst.close();
    rs.close();
    conn.close();


  } catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}

 }
```

Comment: While this may work for now, you are going to run into BIG problems in the future as your application grows. I highly recommend reading up on the MCV model...

Comment: Also, on a side note, you can empty any list by calling `list.clear()`.

Comment: @Zephyr I posted wrong answer, because I had some bugs in combobox listing. But your comment with list.clear(); helped me. Thanx a lot! I will rewrite my answer

Comment: @Zephyr by the way, I use Controller(QuestController) Model (Cards Class) and View(FXML) is this MVC? or I just did wrong code for MVC pattern?

Comment: Yes, you have code for updating the database along with code that updates the UI, in the same class/method. That's a violation of the MVC pattern. You basically want your datasource classes to know nothing about your UI and vice versa.

Comment: @Zephyr Can you give me a link for a good video tutorial how to learn MVC with Controllers in JavaFX?